# How to handle more than 3000 values load on select options dropdown

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am using select options `Select2` JQuery Plugin. and i have 3000 product list for the master data. I tried to load values for the master data to select option (dropdown) in javascript. Data is loaded. i add dynamic table row to load the product list in select options.

When i added 5 and above rows the browse was killed automatically.

```
<select>
   <option value="0">[SELECT]</option>
   <option value="1">Product1</option>
   <option value="2">Product2</option>.....Etc
</select>
```

How to load my product list, If any other search options please share me. Thanks.

Comment: That'd be a prohibitively large dropdown list, both for browser performance and user experience. I'd suggest you find a way to group them into smaller sets of options.

Comment: you should be able to get more than 5 rows without the browser aborting!!

Comment: One word: "filter".  No one can fathom an entire product catalog at once.  Amazon has figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

Populate the data dynamically as the user types the text, but display only max. 20 values. Use input of type 'search', when it is not supported then implement your own input with result div.